# How can I get WAN connectivity on my Pi using an iPhone 5S hotspot?

Tags: raspbian, pi-3, hotspot, ios

I want to use my iPhone as a hotspot for my raspberry pi 3 but cannot get WAN connectivity, only LAN.  The hotspot works as expected with my macbook.  I have the latest version of Jessie raspbian OS.  Removing the apostrophe makes the SSID work ok, but not access the internet.

Any help greatly appreciated.

iPhone 5S running 10.1.1

Comment: Which "apostrophe"?

Comment: Initially, the phone was called Alan's iPhone, which caused issue on the pi, but removal of the ' make it connect ok.  I can now connect but only to a local network, it seems that the iphone in hotspot mode is not routing correctly.

Comment: You need to provide more information to get any sensible answers. At the least include the output of `ifconfig` and details of how you set up WiFi on the Pi.

Comment: Milliways, I was just compiling the ifconfig data but all has started working. I updated to iOS 10.2.1 and all is well.  Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

How I understand, you have an issue with a special character ("apostrophe") in the SSID. Probably "Yourname's iPhone". The easiest way is to change the broadcasted SSID in your iPhones "Personal Hotspot" Settings.

If this is no option, try to escape the apostrophe on your RPI settings:

```
ssid="YourNAme\'s iPhone"
```

General setup for WIFI from [this site](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/configuration/wireless/wireless-cli.md):

> In Terminal, open the wpa-supplicant configuration file in nano:
>
> ```
> sudo nano /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf
> ```
>
> Go to the bottom of the file and add the following:
>
> ```
> network={
>     ssid="name_of_your_wifi"
>     psk="Your_wifi_password"
> }
> ```
>
> Now  by press `Ctrl+X` to close nano, then `Y` to confirm to save your changes, then finally press Enter.
>
> At this point, wpa-supplicant will normally notice a change has occurred within a few seconds, and it will try and connect to the network. If it does not, either manually restart the interface with `sudo ifdown wlan0` and `sudo ifup wlan0`, or reboot your Raspberry Pi with `sudo reboot`.
>
> You can verify if it has successfully connected using `ifconfig wlan0`. If the inet addr field has an address beside it, the Pi has connected to the network. If not, check your password and SSID are correct.

Answer (score 0):

Which Raspberry Pi are you using? Only the RPI 3 has onboard WiFi support. If you're using another model, then you'll have you to get a usb WIFi dongle.

If you do have one, make sure it is supported Raspbian. Some dongles are not and that could be a cause. To verify, boot up to the PIXEL desktop and on the top right toolbar, you should see a wifi logo which you can use to connect to hotspots. If that is not present, then your dongle is not connected.

If you're desperate to be able to connect to a WiFi network, you'll have to buy a support dongle such as [this one](https://thepihut.com/products/usb-wifi-adapter-for-the-raspberry-pi)

Comment: Raspberry Pi 3.

Comment: Is your Pi able to find other broadcasting networks? @AlanWoodward

Comment: As far as I can tell, it can only see things local like the hotspot and another connected laptop, anything other than the subnet is unreachable.

Comment: Are you able to access the WAN from other devices connected to your phone?

Comment: Yes, the attached laptop is working as advertised, including browsing stack exchange ;-)